# derive unordered lists from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I have an array of sentences that I wish to convert to unordered HTML lists each containing the words of a single sentence e.g [I play piano the can'] t

```
<ul>
<li> id = number</li>
<li>I</li>
<li>play</li>
<li>piano</li>
<li>the</li>
<li>can</li>
</ul>
```

I am using the following to ( I wish!!) iterate through the array to get the format that I want

```js
    function makeQuest() {
      var quest=['I play piano the can', 'tired I am', 'are seven There week in a days'];
     
      for (var i=0; i< quest.length; i++){
            document.write('<ul class ="div3">')
         document.write('<li id = "number">' + (i + 1) + '.' + ' '+ '</li>')
       for (var j=0; j < quest[i].length; j++){
        document.write('<li>')
        document.write(quest[i][j]) 
        document.write('</li>' + '</ul>')
         }
        }  
     };
     makeQuest()
```

Instead I get using this script:

```
1.I
play piano the can
2. t
ired I am
3. a
re seven There week in a days.
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `document.write()` is the wrong tool for this job. Build the entire string of list items. Then once the entire string is complete, use `innerHTML`. Alternatively, you can create new nodes and append them to the DOM individually using `.createElement()`.

Comment: If `quest[i]` is a string, why not use `split` on it rather than processing it character by character?

Comment: I applied the quest[i].split()  which gives me the output that I want, however I am applying sortable to this and want each word to be sortable. I think that all I have managed is to get the whole sentence into one <li> tag rather than each word in a separate <li> tag. I am afraid that I am not a programmer, just trying to make a language tutor for personal use: Once I iterate through the array and "capture" a sentence, how do I use split to insert each word into a separate tag?  I am sure that this is a very basic question, so please excuse me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` the strings on spaces (your approach goes by characters instead of words):

```js
function makeQuest() {
  var quest=['I play piano the can', 'tired I am', 'are seven There week in a days'];

  for (var i=0; i< quest.length; i++){
    document.write('<ul class ="div3">')
    document.write('<li>' + (i + 1) + '. </li>')
    for (var j=0; j < quest[i].split(' ').length; j++){
      document.write('<li>')
      document.write(quest[i].split(' ')[j]) 
      document.write('</li>')
    }
    document.write('</ul>')
  }  
};
makeQuest()
```

And (this is out of scope of your problem) don't use `id="number"` more than once.

More about [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you I would never have got there without this

Comment: Running this for some reason prints the sentences twice over in sequence, sentences 1,2,3 and then sentences 1,2,and 3 again. I can't see why that should happen. Its perfect though otherwise. I have applied sortable to the sentences and sorting works perfectly as well. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Stupid boy that I am!! Called the function twice. Its perfect as you wrote.